# Why can't this 4-byte hex number be converted into an int?

Tags: java, type-conversion, hex, value-of

I am looking to create a java method that takes a 4-byte signed hex number and convert it into an int.
However, when I test inputs such as "aaaaaaaa" or "ffffffff"

```
Integer.valueOf("aaaaaaaa", 16)
Integer.valueOf("ffffffff", 16)
```

which should give the values: -1431655766 and -1 respectively.

However, I am getting the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "ffffffff"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:583)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:740)
    at ByteTest.main(ByteTest.java:8)
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: As of Java 8+, use [`parseUnsignedInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseUnsignedInt-java.lang.String-int-), and the result of those two inputs will be `-1431655766` and `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

From the JavaDoc...

*Returns an Integer object holding the value extracted from the specified String when parsed with the radix given by the second argument. The first argument is interpreted as **representing a signed integer** in the radix specified by the second argument, exactly as if the arguments were given to the parseInt(String, int) method.*

An Integer can't hold a positive equivalent of a eight digit hexadecimal value.